# How to make Android POST HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

Yes, I know. I and others have asked similar questions before. I'm looking for help with my specific problem however. I've copied this code near verbatim from other answers, so what have I done wrong here?

```
public void SendName(View v){
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String nombre = name.getText().toString();
        String parameters = "name="+nombre;

        try{
            URL url2 = new URL("*****"); //I've got a correct URL here
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(parameters);
            writer.close();

            os.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The "SendName" function is called onClick from a button in the layout. Everytime I click that button, my application crashes. What gives?

Thus sayeth the Log:

```
12-20 09:56:05.630 17593-17593/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-20 09:56:05.690 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/HyLog: I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
12-20 09:56:05.690 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/HyLog: I : /data/font/config/dfactpre.dat, No such file or directory (2)
12-20 09:56:05.690 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/HyLog: I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19512: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19514: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19518: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-20 09:56:05.760 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 476: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-20 09:56:05.770 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.770 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-20 09:56:05.770 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 498: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-20 09:56:05.770 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
12-20 09:56:05.820 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
12-20 09:56:05.820 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19990: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-20 09:56:05.820 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.830 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
12-20 09:56:05.830 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 290: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
12-20 09:56:05.830 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-20 09:56:05.840 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
12-20 09:56:05.850 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 439: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-20 09:56:05.850 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.850 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
12-20 09:56:05.850 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-20 09:56:05.850 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-20 09:56:05.860 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
12-20 09:56:05.860 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 141 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
12-20 09:56:05.860 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
12-20 09:56:05.910 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 227K, 6% free 4729K/5016K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
12-20 09:56:05.980 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.089_msm8610_KK_3.5_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
                                                                                      Build Date: 01/30/14 Thu
                                                                                      Local Branch: 
                                                                                      Remote Branch: quic/kk_3.5_rb1.21
                                                                                      Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                      Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.089 +  NOTHING
12-20 09:56:06.010 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-20 09:56:06.540 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41c00770 time:6431179
12-20 09:56:13.060 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-20 09:56:13.060 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41c00770 time:6437691
12-20 09:56:13.080 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-20 09:56:13.530 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-20 09:56:13.800 17593-17593/blacktentdigital.com.bintheredumpthatatl I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41c00770 time:6438430
```

Comment: please share your logcat here

Comment: I'm guessing issue is probably because you're invoking this on main thread?  BTW take a look at `Retrofit` - it will make your life much easier!

Comment: @bharat7777 Log posted.

Comment: Executing inside AsyncTask ??

Answer (score 0):

```
// I had use this code it is working fine for me try this one 

public class JsonParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not knocking your answer (since it works and mine doesn't) but I'm more looking to fix what I've got instead of going back and starting over from what you've got - do bear in mind, what I have is already copied from someone else. I'll just be in a worse stink if I copy yours and run into similar problems.

Comment: Also, I'm very much interested in learning how this works (not just copy and paste). If you could give some explanation as to why yours works and mine doesn't, that would be much more helpful.